# Bluetoothctl: Running rfkill on a windows machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, bluetooth

I am trying to use this python wrapper I found https://gist.github.com/egorf/66d88056a9d703928f93 on a windows machine.

I get the error: `'rkfill' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

How do I obtain this command to run the wrapper on a windows computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will only work on a Linux machine such as a Raspberry Pi. It will not work on Microsoft Windows.

There is currently no similar functionality on Windows.